# Como faço para renderizar uma matriz de cofusão no templates Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

Minha view está assim.

```
messages = ConfusionMatrix(previsto, esperado)

context = {'messages':messages}
#print(messages)
return render (request, 'apptcc/matriz_confusao.html', context)
```

A página html está assim.

```
<div class="card-body">
     <ul>
       <li>{{ messages }}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Gostaria de corrigir para imprimir em forma de matriz. conforme imagem

[image: figura 1. matriz de confusão]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tente usar a tag `<pre>` no lugar da `<ul><li>`

Comment: Obrigado, Paulo Marques. Deu certo.